# Laravel app URL not working correctly when sending out mails

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have mails that get sent out using a cron on a centos box. The cron calls console/kernal.php where the function get's called to send out the mail

When sending the mail out from within a browser the urls in the mail are correct but when sending with the cron it changes the urls to `localhost`

I have this in my env file

APP_URL =  example.com

And in my `config/app.php` I have this

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'example.com'),
```

I've done everything to book I believe. If I change the the url env var to `http://example.com` then the emails get sent out with the right url's but then entire site then get's redireted to `http://http//example.com`

What is going wrong here. Please help

**EDIT**

Stupid dev mistake. I had a middelware that was redirecting if the host did not match so it would then redirect to http://http//example.com

For any stumbling upon this and my own reference, check middelware. Sorry to the guys who tried to help.

Comment: `http://example.com` is the correct value to set. When you say the entire site gets redirected to `http://http//example.com`, what exactly are you referring to? The `route` or `url` generators? Or have you hard coded the app url with the `http://` prefix in your views? Try clearing your config to check if the cached value is causing the issue `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: If I navigate to any route in the browser it adds `http://http//example.com` when using http:// in the url configs. I tried clearing the cache but that didn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Use full URL with protocol (not only domain) in `.env`

```
APP_URL=http://example.com
```

And in `config/app.php`

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://example.com'),
```