# How to remove localhost from password reset link in laravel

Tags: laravel

I hosted my laravel application and my problem is when the user click on forgot password link and post the form a password reset link is sent to the user email and when the user clicks the link the user is redirected to **localhost/password/reset/9233da73237c57268f837bcae3cd9ab2fc31be1a69e44451684ed3ed73bc5c24** but the user should be redircted to **mydomain/password/reset/9233da73237c57268f837bcae3cd9ab2fc31be1a69e44451684ed3ed73bc5c24** If anybody knows the solution please answer

Comment: is `url` variable set in config/app.php?

Comment: have done but not working

Comment: If you just changed it, reload any config caches.

Comment: meaning...........?

Comment: The command `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: but can we run this command on the server?

Comment: Yes you can run this command if you have SSH access in server... Also show the code for password reset

Comment: ok..................

Comment: $this->get(basename(base_path()).'/password/reset/{token}/', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');

Comment: the above code is sending password reset link

Comment: Have you tried changing APP url in .env file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change APP_URL in **.env** file

from

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

to

```
APP_URL=http://yourdomain.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write your own notification to replace the one in the vendor library, and set the 'action' passed to the template.

See here http://novate.co.uk/changing-the-laravel-5-3-password-reset-email-text/

Comment: but I think this for changing the text

Comment: but I have to change localhost to my domain

Comment: Well you can set full address give it every thing you want

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and setting the APP_URL variable doesn't solve the problem even after clearing the config cache with "php artisan config:clear".

Comment: And I just resolved the problem after finding the post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44247511/laravel-app-url-not-working-correctly-when-sending-out-mails - simply also change the url variable in the config/app.php